# Disable and Enable Internet without disconnecting wifi

Tags: command-line, wireless

I need a way to disable and then enable internet access via command line while still remaining connected to wifi.

Comment: Which network do you mean? Your LAN?

Comment: any kind of internet access, I would like to restrict my ability to use the internet between the hours of 1pm - 5pm. While remaining connected via wifi. (the reason for this is that connecting to my router is usually a bit troublesome but the connection is good if I remain connected)

Comment: Hnn, pull the cable from the wall?

Comment: Nice idea,  but I don't think there is a terminal command for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Removing your default gateway should do the trick, you'll still be able to reach everything in your subnet, but not outside of it. IIRC this should work, cannot try it atm, replace the IP with your routers IP (in the same subnet):

```
 sudo route del default gw 192.168.1.1
```

Edit: To undo it, this should work:

```
 sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

To find your default gateways IP:

```
route -n|grep "^0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this doesnt seem to be working: SIOCDELRT: No such process

Comment: You'll need to use the correct IP address. It should be in the second column of 'route -n|grep "^0.0.0.0"'

Comment: i was copying the wrong ip

Comment: @JakobLenfers mention in your answer that the IP should be in the same subset.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu now has an option under wifi network settings to limit connection use to local resources.

**Settings > Wifi > Gear Icon > IPv4/IPv6**

Check the tickbox next to *use this connection only for resources on its network*

[image: settings dialog window]

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is rejecting all packets using firewall rule accept all packets within your network, when you want things normal just remove this firewall rule, make a script and run with cron. For more refer https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html, I have not tried this yet but will try it later. Let me know if you try it before me.

Comment: Have you tried it?